# C# MVC Kendo Grid doesn't display data but seems to know it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to implement a Kendo MVC Grid into an university assignment, my problem is that the grid says "No Data" but when I click at one of the column names it shows me some text which contains the data that should be in the grid. Pictures:

[My Grid in my browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQbk2.png)

[What gets displayed when I click one of the column names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvmoS.png)

My Code:

The Controller for the Grid:

```
public class KurseSuchenGridController : Controller
{
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

public ActionResult KurseSuchenGrid()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Kurse_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    IQueryable<Kurs> kurse = db.Kurse;
    DataSourceResult result = kurse.ToDataSourceResult(request, kurs => new {
        Id = kurs.Id,
        Titel = kurs.Titel,
        Inhaltsbeschreibung = kurs.Inhaltsbeschreibung,
        Agenda = kurs.Agenda,
        Ortsangabe = kurs.Ortsangabe,
        Termin = kurs.Termin,
        Anmeldeschluss = kurs.Anmeldeschluss,
        //gelistet = kurs.gelistet,
        ApplicationUserId = kurs.ApplicationUserId
    });

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    db.Dispose();
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

My View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Plattform.Models.Kurs>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Titel);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Inhaltsbeschreibung);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Agenda);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Ortsangabe);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Termin);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Anmeldeschluss);

        columns.Bound(c => c.ApplicationUserId);
      })
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable(sortable => {
          sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn);
      })
      .Filterable(filterable => filterable.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
      .Scrollable()
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Read(read => read.Action("Kurse_Read", "KurseSuchenGrid"))
          .PageSize(20)
      )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are doing server operation. If so, you might want to add `ServerOperation(true)`, also add `Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Id))`, and  add `[HttpPost]` to action method.

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
   .Ajax()
   .ServerOperation(true) <=====
   .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Id)) <=====
   .Read(read => read.Action("Kurse_Read", "KurseSuchenGrid"))
   .PageSize(20)
      )

[HttpPost] <=====
public ActionResult Kurse_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add model like this:

```
.Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(b => b.field1);
        model.Field(b => b.field2);
        model.Field(b => b.field3);
        model.Field(b => b.field4);
        model.Field(b => b.field5);
        ...
    })
```